# Execute monadic code from newly created monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, lifting

I currently have two monads who share the same types, implemented similar to a `State` monad:

```
newtype FooRead  a = FooRead  { runFooRead  :: Context -> (a,Context) }
newtype FooWrite a = FooWrite { runFooWrite :: Context -> (a,Context) }
```

The difference between them is that the first only allows reading of the context (bind will not change it), while the second allows editing the context as well.

There are then functions who use the context in `FooRead` to compute some value without changing the state of the context:

```
getVal :: FooRead a
getVal = do x <- ...
            return x
```

Now I want to execute one of these reading functions from code in the writer monad:

```
writeFunc :: FooWrite ()
writeFunc = do x <- liftVal getVal
            ...
```

Where `liftVal :: FooRead a -> FooWrite a` is a function that extracts the value returned by the `FooRead` function and rolls it into a `FooWrite` monad. This is all good.

However, I can not figure out a way to roll the execution of `getVal`in the above into the context from my `FooWrite` monad. With the above implementation, `getVal` will be run in an empty instance of the monad.

I can figure out how to construct a `FooRead` instance using a `FooWrite` context as

```
lower :: FooWrite a -> FooRead a
```

Essentially I want to demote my writer to a reader, execute code within the reader, the re-promote it to a writer.

But not how to actually execute code within this monad?

Comment: you need to create monad trnsformer `FooReadT` (or `FooWriteT`) and extend your monad `FooWrite` (or `FooRead`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd implement this. First, if you want `Writer` to be strictly more powerful than `Reader` than we'd want a function

```
liftReader :: FooReader a -> FooWriter a
liftReader (FooReader a) = FooWriter a
```

This works because they're structurally equivalent and their monad instances should be isomorphic.

Then we can just

```
t :: FooWriter Int
t = liftReader getVal
```

If you want to be able to go the other way, it's pretty easy

```
liftWriter :: FooWriter a -> FooReader a
liftWriter (FooWriter a) = FooReader a
```

Now the fact that we can lift these types into each other makes you think that they're somehow equivalent.. And in fact they are, you basically have

```
import Control.Monad.State
newtype FooReader s a = FooReader (State s a)
newtype FooWriter s a = FooWriter (State s a)
```

And `State` provides `get` and `put` which are analogous to your `getVal`  and `writeFunc`

Comment: Hi jozefg. I have figured out how to implement something like `liftWriter` and `liftReader` (they're roughly equivalent to `lower` and `liftVal` in my example).
The problem is I want to execute `FooReader` monadic code like `getVal` from my `FooWriter` by transferring the context from my `FooWriter`.
Running something like `do a <- liftReader getVal` would still run `getVal` with an empty context. Instead I would like to use the context from the `FooWriter` that calls it with `liftReader`.

Comment: @jlicht I'm confused here, can you clarify what you mean by context? With `liftWriter/Reader` you have access to all the context of the surrounding monad, eg the state.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. I thought your `liftWriter` and `liftReader` worked the same way as the ones I had implemented. I had another whirl at it, and it seems to work.
Thanks, accepted!

Comment: @jozefg The liftReader above is fine, but the liftWriter returns a FooReader that might be able to change the Context. I suggest instead `liftWriter (FooWriter a) = FooReader $ \s -> (fst (a s), s)`

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I know, this is deliberate. The OP specified that this is running in the same context and I wanted to show how this is isomorphic to `State`

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not using a `lower`-esque function (`liftWriter`) in my code, but good to know for future reference.